# What do you mean by private and public smart contract in private blockchain ethereum? How to create it?

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity

**What I have done**
1. A running private blockchain.
2. written and deploy a smart contract.
3. smart contract works fine on my private blockchain

**What I want**
1. Only authorized account can access my contract, not by another one.
 
2. i want to maintain transaction log of contract, which account access that contract and which method that account accessed.

Comment: This is not clear. Do you want to restrict which accounts can modify a contract in some way? (Write permissions/guards) Do you want to restrict which accounts can read some data inside a contract (encryption/hashes). Or something else?

Comment: @JackWinters, Yes this is what i want "Do you want to restrict which accounts can modify a contract in some way?".

Answer (score 2):

So it sounds like you just need the two patterns: [access restrictions](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/common-patterns.html#restricting-access) and [Events](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/structure-of-a-contract.html#events). The first throws if the caller is not on some list. The second adds events to the contract's [event log](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1302/where-do-contract-event-logs-get-stored-in-the-ethereum-architecture). So if you just had one single user your contract would look something like:

```
contract SomeContract {

    //Assigned when contract is created so if you create it it is you
    address public owner = msg.sender; 

    event LogAccessAttempt(address account, string function, uint timestamp); // Event

    // This could be any function
    function someFunction()
    {
      // Do logging
      LogAccessAttempt(msg.sender,"someFunction",now);
      //only allow the owner to call this function
      if (msg.sender !=owner) throw;
      // do something else
    }

    // You can assign ownership using this function
    function changeOwner(address _newOwner)
    {
        LogAccessAttempt(msg.sender,"changeOwner",now);
        //only allow the owner to call this function
        if (msg.sender !=owner) throw;
        owner = _newOwner;
    }
}
```

As you have more functions this will probably get a little tedious so you could improve this by using modifiers and also you probably want multiple authorised accounts e.g

```
contract SomeContract {

mapping(address => bool) public users;   
users[msg.sender]=true;
modifier guardAndLog(string msg )
        {
            LogAccessAttempt(msg.sender,msg,now);
            if(!users[msg.sender])
               throw
            _;
        }

    function addUser(address _newUser)
    guardAndLog("someone tried to add a user")
    {
       users[_newUser]=true
    }

    function someFunction()
     guardAndLog("someone tried to access someFunction")
    {
    // Do something
    }

   }
```

Comment: What is "addrs"  above code ?   
 `modifier guardAndLog(string msg )
        {
            LogAccessAttempt(msg.sender,msg,now);
            for(i = 0; i < addrs.length; ++i) 
            if(!users[msg.sender])
               throw
            _;
        }`
@JackWinters

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake have deleted the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about private transaction between two nodes, it's not possible with Ethereum. Check out JP Morgan's Quorum. 
https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum