# What happened if a Ethereum client do not have one event?

Tags: nodes, light-clients

Reading [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1302/where-do-contract-event-logs-get-stored-in-the-ethereum-architecture), I understand that as long as you have the blockchain then you have all the events/logs.

But if a dapp is reading data from a light Ethereum client, how will this light client answer?

a) The light Ethereum client will answer only the events that the light Ethereum client has

b) The light Ethereum client will seek for more information in a full node and will answer with all events

c) The light Ethereum client will return an error

d) There is no specification to that and no good practice

e) N.A.

Comment: I'm not certain about it but an educated guess is that it simply doesn't return anything. At least answer B is not correct.

Comment: Geth light client implementation will request the missing data to a full node and wait for answers. If the full node doesn't reply on time it will return an error like data not available. It will not return part of the request.