# Does anyone know how I can get this to sync to the network - no blocks downloading

Tags: go-ethereum, mist

I have been trying to get my Mist application to sync to the Ethereum network.  I tried running geth directly also, screen shots below.

Blockchain not syncing

[image: geth]

[image: Mist]

Comment: Are downloading the ETH (hard-forked) or ETC (non-hard-forked) blockchain? If you are downloading the ETC blockchain, there are less nodes out there to sync with.

Comment: Hi,  I am syncing with ETH blockchain.

Answer (score 1):

Are you downloading (syncing with) the block chain for the first time? If so, it will take some time due to the [size](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/143/what-are-the-ethereum-disk-space-needs) of the block chain.

Just to make sure there is no connectivity related issue you can use [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and check whether peer discovery is working (packets are exchanged between your machine and the default **geth** bootstrap nodes:

```
// FrontierBootNodes are the enode URLs of the P2P bootstrap nodes running on
// the Frontier network.
var FrontierBootNodes = []*discover.Node{
    // ETH/DEV Go Bootnodes
    discover.MustParseNode("enode://a979fb575495b8d6db44f750317d0f4622bf4c2aa3365d6af7c284339968eef29b69ad0dce72a4d8db5ebb4968de0e3bec910127f134779fbcb0cb6d3331163c@52.16.188.185:30303"), // IE
    discover.MustParseNode("enode://de471bccee3d042261d52e9bff31458daecc406142b401d4cd848f677479f73104b9fdeb090af9583d3391b7f10cb2ba9e26865dd5fca4fcdc0fb1e3b723c786@54.94.239.50:30303"),  // BR
    discover.MustParseNode("enode://1118980bf48b0a3640bdba04e0fe78b1add18e1cd99bf22d53daac1fd9972ad650df52176e7c7d89d1114cfef2bc23a2959aa54998a46afcf7d91809f0855082@52.74.57.123:30303"),  // SG

    // ETH/DEV Cpp Bootnodes
    discover.MustParseNode("enode://979b7fa28feeb35a4741660a16076f1943202cb72b6af70d327f053e248bab9ba81760f39d0701ef1d8f89cc1fbd2cacba0710a12cd5314d5e0c9021aa3637f9@5.1.83.226:30303"),
}

// TestNetBootNodes are the enode URLs of the P2P bootstrap nodes running on the
// Morden test network.
var TestNetBootNodes = []*discover.Node{
    // ETH/DEV Go Bootnodes
    discover.MustParseNode("enode://e4533109cc9bd7604e4ff6c095f7a1d807e15b38e9bfeb05d3b7c423ba86af0a9e89abbf40bd9dde4250fef114cd09270fa4e224cbeef8b7bf05a51e8260d6b8@94.242.229.4:40404"),
    discover.MustParseNode("enode://8c336ee6f03e99613ad21274f269479bf4413fb294d697ef15ab897598afb931f56beb8e97af530aee20ce2bcba5776f4a312bc168545de4d43736992c814592@94.242.229.203:30303"),

    // ETH/DEV Cpp Bootnodes
}
```

).

Comment: Thanks 

This is not the first time syncing to the blockchain.  Appreicate the code snippet.  I will have a look in wireshark.

Comment: Make sure you are using the same data directory otherwise `geth` will re synchronize.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a solution

```
geth.exe removedb
```

which cleared the chain and then

```
geth.exe --fast --cache=2048
```

to resync