# Mist not synching/opening

Tags: mist, wallets, network

My hard drive was recently replaced due to internal damage and the old data was uploading onto the new hard drive. Since then when opening ethereum wallet 0.7.3 it is stuck and wount synch. the message it is showing is

> "Found running Ethereum Node! "

what is this, what does it mean? So i downloaded the latest version 0.8.1 and that is stuck " searching for network.." and will not synch either.

Ive tried `geth --fast` commands, set the date and time..all the obvious and such but nothing seems to change.

Comment: What is the [node log](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Mist-Troubleshooting-Guide) saying?

Answer (score 2):

> What is this, what does it mean?

It means that your client (MIST) has found a node with which it can sync (download its copy of the block chain).

> So i downloaded the latest version 0.8.1 and that is stuck " searching
>   for network.." and will not sync either.

Syncing takes [time](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/143/what-are-the-ethereum-disk-space-needs); you are downloading the whole block chain (also, make sure you have enough disk space).