# Ethereum blockchain size as of March 2017 (geth --fast and others)

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, synchronization

What is the size of the Ethereum blockchain as of March 2017?

I am just starting with `geth --fast -cache=1024`, but I would also be interested in other clients or other downloading methods.

I know the question has been [asked](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/143/what-are-the-ethereum-disk-space-needs) in the past, but it would be interesting to keep an up-to-date answer.

Comment: Let's rather keep the original thread updated than posting a new question once in a while.