# The exact size of Ethereum full node blockchain

Tags: nodes

I have been trying to get the answer to this question for an article that i am writing:'What is de current size of a full node (e.g. a node that has the encapsulates the whole ethereum blockchain which is needed for upholding the network), and how has that full node progressed from the inception of ethereum until now? preferably with a link of up to data.

The smallest full node possible (i heard parity is also a full node but haven't heard back from parity concerning this).

My question is similar to [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13280/ethereum-blockchain-size-as-of-march-2017-geth-fast-and-others) question, but it was left unanswered

Comment: There is nothing like the exact size of a full node blockchain. There are many variables, i.e. client used, pruning and database configuration, etc. Let's try to keep all that in one thread and let's keep this updated. If you need current figures for your article, please ping me (@5chdn) on [parity gitter](https://gitter.im/paritytech/parity). I can help you getting sorted.