# What is the actual blockchain size?

Tags: blockchain

I am trying to find the actual size of the etherum blockchain.

I just found older posts that says it is around 21GB.

[What are the Ethereum disk space needs?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/143/what-are-the-ethereum-disk-space-needs)

Comment: found a 2 month old answer on reddit, this should do it for the moment.

https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/5om2lw/current_ethereum_blockchain_size/

Comment: Is there a blockchain.info like thing for eth? like this: https://blockchain.info/charts/avg-block-size?timespan=2years

Comment: they are https://etherchain.org/ and https://etherscan.io/

Answer (score 14):

Blockchain size in ethereum depends in the implementation. In Parity is about 6 GB, in Geth is about 11 GB. Geth is not implementing state pruning, so 11 GB would be a clean sync with --light, while if you don't use this would be 60GB+.

For disk space needs, see this answer.

[What are the Ethereum disk space needs?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/143/what-are-the-ethereum-disk-space-needs)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but i already checked this link as you can see above :) 

Now I am downloading the chain to see how big it is.

Comment: If you got that answer from here: https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/5om2lw/current_ethereum_blockchain_size/ then there's actually the hint that it's not --light but --fast

Comment: @Dan Kinchen Are you sure it's 11 GB with `--light` option and not with `--fast` option?