# What is the size of the blockchain in 2017?

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets

I have been running the geth with the --fast option to get the blockchain. So far my computer has been running for nearly two days only this program.

The current size of my chaindata folder is 30 GB, and I am on block 1950132. It looks like it is over half way done, but I noticed it's finding less and less blocks as time goes on.

My concern is that my hard drive will fill up before the blockchain is finished. Does anybody know exactly how big the geth blockchain is as of today?

Are there any other ways to get around downloading the full chain to be able to run the ethereum wallet properly?

Comment: currently with geth --fast, for me its 32Gb

Comment: There is nothing like the _definite_ size of a blockchain. It heavily depends on your client's database implementation and applied pruning options.

Answer (score 6):

You can check that there are 3,433,816 blocks in the official blockchain. You can check it on [ethstats](https://ethstats.net/).

You can also check the size of the blockchain on this [post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/160/4733).

Comment: Is there anyway to estimate the size of the blockchain when you know the number of blocks? I'm guessing since each block is a different size, there is not easy to tell?

Comment: The second link I sent you mentioned that the Ethereum blockchain is at least 75GB. And that was in November 2016. That was your concern. Moreover, you can also calculate the groth of the blockchain with the link above.

Comment: It seems every estimate is different based on all the threads I have found including the one linked. That is additional 4 months where development and transactions have been the heaviest. So how do you calculate it? I don't see anything in that link which says how to calculate it exactly, except someone writing it grows at 1GB a month, which is obviously outdated now.

Comment: The Ethereum network can scale, depending how much Gas the transactions needs. So a block does not have a fixed size like in Bitcoin, and can "grow" if a giant transaction comes and consume all the Gas from the block. So, imho, there is no precise calculation possible. Moreover,the size of the blockchain with the client `geth ` and the `--fast`  method should be around 11GB.