# Ethereum chain size

Tags: blockchain, hardware

Currently I don't have an up to date version of the real/test net on my PC.  I've tried to find a blockchain explorer that will show the size of the chain in GB.  Specifically for Geth, or atleast for any other clients.

Question:  To date what is the current chain size in GB?

Comment: I was asking this question yesterday but nobody seems to know for sure: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13628/what-is-the-size-of-the-blockchain-in-2017/13633#13633

On reddit one person told me the blockchain is 140 GB. What is recommended is to run 'geth --fast console' which will get a version of the blockchain which is only 12 GB. The fast version just contains the headers... I think most people are running this version.

Answer (score 2):

I found a website, where apparently somebody runs a full node and grabs a screen cap of the chaindata folder size every so often.
It does not appear to be dynamic, but it is the most recent thing I could dig up. It is 210 GB as of 04-November 2017.

the URL is [ethereumchainsize·com](http://ethereumchainsize.com/)