# 1 week to download and syn just one third of the blockchain ... despite using geth

Tags: synchronization

I am a newbie, also having severel trouble downloading/syncing the blockchain. 
Mist Wallet 0.81 installed, got it working about half a year ago, but not now any.

I tried a complete download using geth 1.6.5, I got the entire chain downloaded including some error messages over the two and a half days period, but starting the mist wallet, it started a new download all over again...

Now - 7 days (!) later - mist is at 1,1 Mio of 3,8 Mio, created 21 GB (!) in my chain folder and my harddrive on c: has just about 4 GB left...

I am kind of frustrated - and thankful any advice: most urgent problem appears to be

1) How do I alter the chainfolder and references that folder in mist and geth?

2) How do I get it finally get the blockchain downloaded AND accepted by mist (any log files for examples which I need to shift from one folder to another? etc?)

Comment: if you don't have a reason to download the blockchain you could use the light client.

Comment: Which OS are you using? Mist will not start geth if it is already running. Which parameters were used when syncing geth?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good listing of the different clients and how big the blockchain can be, if you not prune it. I use the default parity implementation with a 10GB blockchain, for example 
[What are the Ethereum disk space needs?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/143/what-are-the-ethereum-disk-space-needs)