# Where is Ethereum hosted?

Tags: blockchain

I understand the Ethereum is decentralized. But shouldn't there be some primary nodes that host it? Kind of like the internet has primary nodes that originated in universities?

I mean the blockchain. where is it..

Answer (score 1):

Ethereum is decentralized. It doesn't have any primary nodes. You can see a map of miners on https://ethstats.net/

Comment: I get that it's decentralized. But SOMEONE needs to host it. are the miners hosting it somehow?

Comment: By ethereum are you talking about the documentation and code or the instance of the block chain?

Comment: the blockchain..

Answer (score 0):

Put simply, the blockchain is stored at each of the nodes.

If you run an Ethereum client like Mist on your computer, the blockchain data is on your computer.

The various clients have methods of managing just how much of the data is stored (e.g. pruning), so most people will not have an entire copy of  every block just sitting in storage.

You can read more about that [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/143/what-are-the-ethereum-disk-space-needs)

Comment: Is it possible somehow a part of it can never be restored because the node holding it ceased to exist?