# What happens to my blockchain download if there is a sudden ISP outage?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, mining, ether

I've been downloading the blockchain using Geth --rpc so that my computer can mine ethereum, however it's been downloading for 3 days and is at roughly 23GB's in size (yesterday it was 25GB's). Though I was curious what would happen to the blockchain I've already downloaded, if my internet experienced an outage before the blockchain completed?

I assume it would simply keep trying until the connection resumed, but this is new to me. If I may also ask, what is the current size of the blockchain? I don't mind the wait, I would just like an idea of where I'm at, if it's around 80% done, 50% done, or what. :)

Also if it helps my ISP speed is 50MB's download, my computer has 16GB's RAM, i5-3570K CPU, 1080TI FTW GPU, Windows 10Pro, and about 200GB's of free space on the hard drive.

Please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: Is your disk SSD? Using `--syncmode fast` over an SSD disk should download the blockchain in less than a day, a couple of hours with a fast internet connection. Entering `web3.eth.syncing` in the geth console will show the current progress, most recent block is 3966826, as of 2017-07-03 07:38 GMT.

Comment: Concerning the blockchain size check https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/143/what-are-the-ethereum-disk-space-needs

Comment: Thank you BadrBellaj. My hard drive is just a SATA. I'll keep note of the web3.eth.syncing. Once the download finishes I need to find a program to work with Geth, that will make it easier to understand everything I'm looking at. Hopefully in GUI interface. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will continue downloading from where you left off. You can also stop the app and open it again and it'll continue downloading from where it left off.

Without the --light flag in Geth, the blockchain size will be about 60 GB so you're almost halfway there since it looks like you didn't use that flag.

Comment: Thank you JaTochNietDan! I didn't know about the --light flag or really any shortcuts. I suppose I could stop it and re-start it with the flag, to make it faster but would that interfere with mining afterward? I'm hesitant to do anything that might mess it up. I started the process based a guide that I found http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/ethereum-mining-101-your-complete-guide_us_58b6e1eee4b02f3f81e44e9f 

By any chance is there a site with an beginners guide to mining or at least a list of flags? Also, is there a GUI interface available for this? Just thought I'd ask. Thank you.