# Is it possible to sync on the testnet -Ethereum-?

Tags: blockchain, testnets, ethereumjs

I want to learn about blockchain and installed ethereum, web3, node.js and npm in a VM.

The problem is that this machine has only 512MB ram, 5GB Disk e CPU I don't really have an idea but wouldn't say it is too powerful.

Is it possible to sync on the testnet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the Ethereum disk space needs?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/143/what-are-the-ethereum-disk-space-needs)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too specific to one specific computer setup.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can not sync the test network.

My Parity node (with --warp sync) on the Ropsten test network uses 7.1 GB of space.

I have tried syncing a node with 512MB of ram. The node crashes. 1GB is the minimum.

Geth tends to (from my tests) use more space, and a similar amount of memory.

I suggest you setup a $10 [Linode](https://www.linode.com/) if you want to run a Ropsten node.

Comment: If I want to develop applications daap, will I have to download the testnet and eventually the live blockchain?
Any workarounds to avoid something like that or even that all the users of my app to download the whole blockchain?